# How can I translate the days and months with Poedit?

Tags: php, poedit

I use Poedit to translate my website but I am stuck on how to translate the days of the week and the months if I display them with php like this:

`$day_of_week_in_words->format("l")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server has the LC language library you can simply use php functions without any poedit interactions You can find the details here [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
simple examples:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");
echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A,"); //%A means A full textual representation of the day    Sunday through Saturday
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %A and");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
echo strftime(" in German %A.\n");
```

Comment: I have some trouble with the encoding but it seems to be what I need. I am looking at some methods like `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');` but when I put .UTF-8 nothing happens, just displays it in english. And this is with every language I tested.

Comment: Okay I resolved the encoding problem. Thank you for letting me know about this function! :)

Comment: Please remember that in your server there should be fr_FR language library forexample my server is CENTOS and lets check the French library installed  `localectl list-locales |grep FR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use php date() to do this.
Check here[manual/en/function.date.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
Do like this

```
$day_of_week_in_words=date('N');//o/p as 4 means Thursday
$day_of_week_in_words=date('n');//o/p as 7 means July
```